# A curious discrepancy between DBCC PAGE and %%physloc%% for System Base Tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, dbcc

During an attempt to dig into some odd system behavior I've come up against a scenario where I'm using the undocumented routine [`DBCC PAGE`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2006/06/10/how-to-use-dbcc-page/) to find some information within a page, but I'm not getting results that entirely make sense.  In this situation, I'd like to see the data stored on a given data page, so I take the approach [outlined in this article](https://littlekendra.com/2016/10/17/decoding-key-and-page-waitresource-for-deadlocks-and-blocking/) by Kendra Little.

First, I execute the following within my user database to return the page header info:

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604)
DBCC PAGE(0, 5, 54023, 3)
```

(Page Header) Results:

```
PAGE: (5:54023)


BUFFER:


BUF @0x000001ACCF30FE40

bpage = 0x000001AC67C0E000          bhash = 0x0000000000000000          bpageno = (5:54023)
bdbid = 7                           breferences = 0                     bcputicks = 0
bsampleCount = 0                    bUse1 = 15247                       bstat = 0x109
blog = 0x8a8a8a8a                   bnext = 0x0000000000000000          bDirtyContext = 0x0000000000000000
bstat2 = 0x0                        

PAGE HEADER:


Page @0x000001AC67C0E000

m_pageId = (5:54023)                m_headerVersion = 1                 m_type = 1
m_typeFlagBits = 0x0                m_level = 0                         m_flagBits = 0x200
m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = 60    m_indexId (AllocUnitId.idInd) = 1   Metadata: AllocUnitId = 281474980642816
Metadata: PartitionId = 281474980642816                                  Metadata: IndexId = 1
Metadata: ObjectId = 60             m_prevPage = (5:54018)              m_nextPage = (0:0)
pminlen = 17                        m_slotCnt = 17                      m_freeCnt = 5119
m_freeData = 3073                   m_reservedCnt = 0                   m_lsn = (458:184912:3)
m_xactReserved = 0                  m_xdesId = (0:0)                    m_ghostRecCnt = 0
m_tornBits = 1366179534             DB Frag ID = 1                      

Allocation Status

GAM (5:2) = ALLOCATED               SGAM (5:3) = NOT ALLOCATED          
PFS (5:48528) = 0x40 ALLOCATED   0_PCT_FULL                              DIFF (5:6) = CHANGED
ML (5:7) = NOT MIN_LOGGED
```

The key takeaways here are `Metadata: ObjectId = 60` and `m_type = 1` (and to a lesser degree `Metadata: IndexId = 1`).  This objectID maps to the `sys.sysobjects` system view, and a page of type `1` [means this page is a data page](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/) (and the indexID maps to the clustered index, `clst`).

Because this is a view and not an actual table, I am unable to query the hidden `%%physloc%%` column as it returns the error `Invalid column name '%%'` when attempted.  Pulling this view's definition via [`sp_helptext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) yields that `sys.sysobjects` actually hits the `sys.sysschobjs$` [system base table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables?view=sql-server-ver15).  Knowing this, I open up the [DAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators?view=sql-server-ver15) and run the following query:

```
SELECT sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter (%%physloc%%),
    *
FROM sys.sysschobjs
ORDER BY 1
```

Formatted, Abbreviated Results:

```
            id          name                                        nsid        nsclass status      type pid         pclass intprop    
----------- ----------- ------------------------------------------- ----------- ------- ----------- ---- ----------- ------ -----------
...
(1:335:9)   86          sysftproperties                             4           0       917505      S    0           1      6          
(5:16:0)    885578193   truncate_table                              1           0       786432      P    0           1      0          
(5:16:1)    978102525   load_doc_dim_from_raw                       5           0       786432      P    0           1      0          
(5:16:10)   1221579390  q_sys_dim_sk                                5           0       512         SO   0           1      0          
(5:16:11)   1237579447  cap_folder_tbl                              5           0       917504      U    0           1      37         
(5:16:12)   1253579504  SYSDATETIME___2141024858                    5           0       131072      D    1237579447  1      37         
(5:16:13)   1269579561  cap_prcss_tbl                               5           0       917504      U    0           1      30         
(5:16:14)   1285579618  SYSDATETIME___2003733077                    5           0       131072      D    1269579561  1      30         
(5:16:2)    994102582   load_fx_to_stg_doc_dim                      5           0       786432      P    0           1      0          
(5:16:3)    1010102639  load_cap_to_stg_doc_dim                     5           0       786432      P    0           1      0          
(5:16:4)    1026102696  load_ob_doc_dim                             5           0       786432      P    0           1      0          
(5:16:5)    1042102753  load_ob_stg_doc_dim_to_dbo_doc_dim          5           0       786432      P    0           1      0          
(5:16:6)    1058102810  load_fx_stg_doc_dim_to_dbo_doc_dim          5           0       786432      P    0           1      0          
(5:16:7)    1074102867  load_cap_stg_doc_dim_to_dbo_doc_dim         5           0       786432      P    0           1      0          
(5:16:8)    1090102924  Load_dbo_doc_dim_from_ech_doc_dim           5           0       786432      P    0           1      0          
(5:16:9)    1205579333  q_doc_dim_sk                                5           0       512         SO   0           1      0          
(5:17:0)    786101841   NEXT_VALUE_FOR_stg_q_doc_dim_sk_1466900491  5           0       131072      D    770101784   1      1          
(5:17:1)    802101898   SYSDATETIME___65475060                      5           0       131072      D    770101784   1      17         

(2528 rows affected)
```

Herein lies the discrepancy...  The results show no page `54023` for data file `5` being used.  I do have some objects appear on data file `5`, but these are limited to pages `16` and `17` (as shown above) with nothing approaching the `50000` mark.  I have validated I'm connected to the proper user database within my DAC connection, so my issue hopefully isn't that trivial.  I've also confirmed this process works as advertised against User tables, so I think the process is sound.

Am I misinterpreting the `DBCC PAGE` results or do system tables follow a different set of rules compared to user tables?  What am I missing here?

I understand if this is closed as *too localized*, but because this is generally a pretty straight forward process, I feel like I'm missing something and am reaching out for some direction.

Comment: You're on the right track with "... do system tables follow a different set of rules compared to user tables?"